# Read array of objects and output values by given conditions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Here is the problem:

Client wants to buy 2 same name PCs both color white or black with the total price less than 1600. Write a JavaScript program that would read given array `var pcs` and would find him the best offers.

```js
var pcs = [
 { "model":"lenovo", "price":1234, "color":{"red":1,"green":2} },
 { "model":"hp", "price":800, "color":{"black":2,"yellow":0} },
 { "model":"toshiba", "price":256, "color":{"mėlyna":3,"green":1} },
 { "model":"dell", "price":697, "color":{"black":1,"white":2} },
 { "model":"acer", "price":620, "color":{"black":4,"white":2} },
 { "model":"apple", "price":2560, "color":{"white":3,"black":1} },
 { "model":"asus", "price":1001, "color":{"black":2,"yellow":3} }
],
    PC,
    Collors,
    offer = "Offers: " + "\n";

for (var i = 0; i < pcs.length; i++) {
    PC = pcs[i]; 
    Collors = Object.keys(PC.color);

    if ((((PC.price) * 2) <= 1600) && (PC.color.black >= 2 || PC.color.white >= 2)) {

        for ( var j = 0; j < Collors.length; j++) {
            
        
            if ((PC.color.black >= 2) && (PC.color.white >= 2)) {

            offer += "\n" + "model: " + PC.model + "\n" + "price: " + (PC.price) * 2 + "\n"
            + "Collors: " + Collors[0] + " and " + Collors[1] + "\n"; 
            }

            else if (((PC.color.black >= 2) && (Collors[j] === "black"))) {

            offer += "\n" + "model: " + PC.model + "\n" + "price: " + (PC.price) * 2 + "\n"
                + "Collors: " + Collors[j] + "\n";      
            }

            else if (((PC.color.white >= 2) && (Collors[j] === "white"))) {

            offer += "\n" + "model: " + PC.model + "\n" + "price: " + (PC.price) * 2 + "\n"
            + "Collors: " + Collors[j] + "\n"; 
            }
        }
    } 
}

console.log(offer);
```

Written code find the best offers, but could someone tell why `acer` in the output duplicates itself and how is possible to repair it?

Many thanks for all help,

Comment: It's outputting acer twice because you're looping over the pcs and looping over the colors for each PC. As two conditions within the second loop over the colors are satisfied, you will get the acers output twice. So, if you want to output acer once, the question is would the customer prefer a black acer or a white acer? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You loop over `Collors`. For `acer` both `black` and `white` have `>2`. So the first rule that checks `black and white` matches once for `black` and once for `white`.

A solution is to not loop over `Collors` at all but check `black` and `white` separately directly:

```js
 var pcs = [
 { "model":"lenovo", "price":1234, "color":{"red":1,"green":2} },
 { "model":"hp", "price":800, "color":{"black":2,"yellow":0} },
 { "model":"toshiba", "price":256, "color":{"melyna":3,"green":1} },
 { "model":"dell", "price":697, "color":{"black":1,"white":2} },
 { "model":"acer", "price":620, "color":{"black":4,"white":2} },
 { "model":"apple", "price":2560, "color":{"white":3,"black":1} },
 { "model":"asus", "price":1001, "color":{"black":2,"yellow":3} }
],
 PC,
 Collors,
 offer = [],
 colors;

for (var i = 0; i < pcs.length; i++) {
 colors = [];
 PC = pcs[i]; 
 if (PC.color.black >= 2) {
  colors.push("black");
 }
 if (PC.color.white >= 2) {
  colors.push("white");
 }
 if (PC.price * 2 <= 1600 && colors.length > 0) {
  offer.push({
   "model": PC.model,
   "total price": PC.price * 2,
   "color": colors
  });
 }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(offer, undefined, "\t"));
```

Comment: Many thank for response @Halcyon. Problem is that possible colors for the offer under 1600 should be shown in one line, like in the question's snippet: `Collors: black and white`. It means that there are 2 black and 2 white PCs in the store.

Comment: Ah, in the case you can do the if-else thing you did. I updated my answer.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to output color in the same manner as `PC.model` and `PC.price` is outputted? I  tried to find workaround using `PC.color` instead of strings, but I am missing the point...

Comment: To correct myself; I wanted to know if it is possible to output variables of color object without using strings?

Comment: Yes! But is there any way to output the offer information in the same format as it was shown in question's snippet while using your method with `JSON.stringify()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Code to solve problem to get required output in console.

```js
var pcs = [
 { "model":"lenovo", "price":1234, "color":{"red":1,"green":2} },
 { "model":"hp", "price":800, "color":{"black":2,"yellow":0} },
 { "model":"toshiba", "price":256, "color":{"mėlyna":3,"green":1} },
 { "model":"dell", "price":697, "color":{"black":1,"white":2} },
 { "model":"acer", "price":620, "color":{"black":4,"white":2} },
 { "model":"apple", "price":2560, "color":{"white":3,"black":1} },
 { "model":"asus", "price":1001, "color":{"black":2,"yellow":3} }
];





for (var i=0; i < pcs.length; i++) {

    if((pcs[i].color.black >=2 || pcs[i].color.white >=2) && pcs[i].price *2 <=1600){
       //console.log (pcs[i]);
        
        var colors = Object.keys(pcs[i].color),
            color = '';
        for(var j = 0; j < colors.length; j++){
            
            if ((pcs[i].color.black >= 2 && colors[j] === "black") ||
                (pcs[i].color.white >= 2 && colors[j] === "white" )) {
                
                
                if (color.length > 0) {
                    color += ' and ' + colors[j];
                    } else {
                            color = colors[j];
                    }
                
                }
        }
        
        
        console.log('Model: ' + pcs[i].model + '\nPrice: ' + pcs[i].price*2 + '\nSpalvos: ' + color);
        
        
    }
}
```